# Using <input type=file /> with J2EE/MySQL Backend

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm wondering how I can hook up an input type=file to send a picture back to a backend servlet that will eventually be stored in a MySQL database as a BLOB? In other words, how can I upload a picture using the input and send that back to the servlet to insert into the database as a BLOB type?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you said it in other words? :) Anyway. it is not a question, but a whole application. Try to divide your task into smaller ones. First, google for "java servlet file uploads". Then implement this function and get familiar with it. Then think, if you really want to store a picture in the database. then think twice. Then store it in the filesystem. That's all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To browse a file for upload, use HTML [`<input type="file">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#file-select). To be able to send the selected file in request body, use [`<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2). To be able to parse the multipart/form-data request, use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). To get an `InputStream` of the uploaded file, use [`FileItem#getInputStream()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getInputStream%28%29). To let Java interact with a database, use [JDBC API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html). To store an `InputStream` in a database, use [`PreparedStatement#setBinaryStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29).